# South migrate raising ValidationError

Tags: python, django, django-south

South is fighting with three fields and I have done my best to pass him and I could not:

```
data = models.DateField(verbose_name=u'Data', null=True, blank=True)
hora = models.TimeField(verbose_name=u'Hora', null=True, blank=True)
criado_em = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=u'Criado em', auto_now_add=True)
```

Its always in `python manage.py migrate app`, the error thrown is:

> ValidationError: [u "'True' value has an invalid format. It must be in
>   HH: MM [: SS [. Uuuuuu]] format."]

I don't know what else to do, I've tried several ways, the last one was this, which also returned the same error above

```
data = models.DateField(verbose_name=u'Data', default=datetime.now)
hora = models.TimeField(verbose_name=u'Hora', default=datetime.now)
criado_em = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=u'Criado em', auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.now)
```

Comment: Please show the migration code that fails.

Comment: @wRAR http://dpaste.com/hold/964342/

Comment: timefield want's time not date so try to change datetime.now into time function. Please search it about python time

Comment: @catherine I already tried to migrate without the datetime, unsuccessfully.

Comment: The code, not just the exception.

Comment: 0002_auto__add_field_evento_hora__add_field_evento_criado_em__chg_field_eve.py line 14

Comment: @wRAR currently it looks [like](http://dpaste.com/hold/981420/) this

Comment: @FilipeManuel I can't see your codes in dpaste...always loading only

Comment: @catherine exception: http://pastebin.com/BS8Ek4En migration code: http://pastebin.com/c8CiD50T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `default=True` on `TimeField` in the migration is wrong. You need to use an appropriate default (and you were asked for it when you created the migration).

Comment: @FilipeManuel his correct, you must remove the default=True or else use correct time function for it

Comment: Just removing it won't help, at least if the table is not empty.